# django start server fails

Tags: python, django

Am trying to run default python default server with virtual environment via

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but am getting an error

> Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?
>   Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?.

I have already enabled the virtual environment

and when i check

```
django-admin --version
```

am getting

```
1.11.7
```

Where could i be going wrong?

Comment: As the error message says: what is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: What does `which python` say

Comment: @mbieren running which python inside the virtual environment am getting /home/geoff/Desktop/apps/newenv/bin/python

Comment: @mbieren running which python outside virtual environment am getting /usr/bin/python

Comment: @JohnGordon running which python returns /usr/bin/python

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI can you run pip freeze inside and outside of the virtualenv, and see in which one is installed?

Comment: Since django-admin works, you can do `django-admin runserver`. I don't know what's wrong with your environment. You can try `python -c 'import django'` to confirm that the virtualenv is indeed activated as expected. What is the contents of your `manage.py` file?

Comment: I didn't ask for `which python`; I asked for your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon how do you get the PYTHONPATH am using linux ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

-Create virtual env

-Install django and other packages needed for project while inside of virtualenv.

-Path python (if you have multiple versions of python on your comp, it needs to know which version to run)

and then finally run

python manage.py runserver

Always work inside a virtual environment. Thats how you keep versions of packages(like django) the same. If you dont use a virtual environment and intstall django 1.9, and then 1.11, you'll be using 1.11. or whatever the last version you installed was. I hear you can also mess up your comp drastically if you dont use a virtual environment. it keeps the project (or disaster) contained.

Comment: from the above question ive stated that ive already enabled virtual environment.

Comment: cflux is right. You have to acivate the virtual env with `source ./env_name/bin/activate` and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside this virtual env